# In Bazaar (bzr), How to show log of only commits which were done in a specific branch nick?

Tags: version-control, bazaar

In Mercurial (hg), a user can enter the following command --

```
hg log --branch branchName
```

This shows only the commits which were done against a specific named branch.

What bzr command can give me the same functionality? I could not find an option for "bzr log" that would do the same thing. For example, if I committed revs 1, 2, and 3 in branch nick "trunk" and 2.1.1, 2.1.2, and 4 in branch nick "ftr-foo", how can I print only the revs under branch nick "ftr-foo" such that I'd only see 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 4? And how would I get only the commits which were done against the "trunk" branch nick such that I'd only see 1, 2, and 3?

DAG graph below.

```
4 [ftr-foo]
|  \
3   \ [trunk]
|    \
|     2.1.2 [ftr-foo]
|      |
|     2.1.1 [ftr-foo]
|   /
|  /
2 [trunk]
|
1 [trunk]
```

Answer (score 0):

While Bzr has the basic machinery to allow matching commits by other criteria, this is still a non-trivial exercise in plugin writing. A simpler alternative is to filter the output of `bzr log` or `bzr log -n0` through a grep-like program that understands where commits begin and end.

The following Python program (which should work with both Python 2.7 and Python 3.x) allows you to grep `bzr log` output for arbitrary regular expressions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, re, os

args = sys.argv[1:]
if not args or args in [["--help"], ["-h"], ["-help"]]:
  prog = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
  print("Usage: bzr log BZRARGS | " + prog + " REGEX ...")
  sys.exit(1)
patterns = [re.compile(pat) for pat in args]

def handle(block):
  match = False
  for line in block:
    for pattern in patterns:
      if re.search(pattern, line):
        match = True
        break
    if match:
      break
  if match:
    try:
      for line in block:
        sys.stdout.write(line)
    except IOError:
      sys.exit(0)

def main():
  sep = "^\s*------------------------------------------------------------$"
  sep = re.compile(sep)
  stdin = sys.stdin
  block = []
  while True:
    line = stdin.readline()
    if not line:
      if block:
        handle(block)
      break
    if re.match(sep, line):
      if not block:
        block.append(line)
      else:
        handle(block)
        block = [ line ]
    else:
      block.append(line)

main()
```

If you call this program `bzr-greplog`, you can then do:

```
bzr log -n0 | bzr-greplog 'branch nick: foo'
```

to search for branches with the nick `foo`. Note that the pattern will match anywhere within a line, so it will match a nick of `foobar` also, for example, or a commit message that happens to have this pattern. In order to avoid (most) such false positives, use an anchored regex instead, e.g. `'^\s*branch nick: foo$'` (the `\s*` is necessary because indented commits may begin with spaces). You can also use a script that allows you to search specifically for a branch nick:

```
#!/bin/sh
bzr log -n0 | bzr-greplog '^\s*branch nick: '"$1"'$'
```

Known bug: If a commit message contains exactly a `bzr log` record separator (with the exact same number of dashes), then `bzr-greplog` will misinterpret the commit as two commits and may leave out the part following the separator.